# How to stream video with subtitles from computer to Ipad?

Tags: ipad, windows, unix, streaming, file-sharing

I would like to stream some movies with downloaded subtitles from my hard drive to my IPad mini.

What are some ways I can achieve that solution?

I use Ubuntu 15.10 or Windows and my IPad is updated with the last iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like VLC Player is the best option for you right now in regards to subtitles on iOS devices.

The site http://www.iphonehacks.com/2014/01/vlc-tips-tricks.html states:

"VLC also includes support for subtitles. Some video formats natively support subtitles while for others, you need a separate .sub file. If you need to add a separate .sub file, name it similar to the video filename, and add it to VLC for iOS via any of the file transfer means described above. VLC will automatically associate the two and show you subtitles."

VLC, on Mac, Windows, and iOS, is as flexible as it gets when it comes to video players, so you can't go wrong with it. It also allows you to wirelessly transfer video from your PC to the app, allowing you to bi-pass iTunes and WMA, which is always a plus ;).

Hope that helps!

Comment: VLC does not play AC3 audio which is a real bummer, Infuse is a superior product but if you wan't AC3 audio you have to upgrade to Pro. There are many more options for connecting with Infuse as well (e.g. SFTP, SMB), it decodes any video codec locally and streams it through AirPlay with no mirroring (no dropped frames). This is the only app that I know of that has that capability.

Answer (score 2):

You can install [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ios.html) or [Infuse](http://firecore.com/infuse) (my favorite) and have them connect to your various machines.